# Laravel validate regex - Email inside text

Tags: php, validation, laravel, email

I need to check the presence of any email within a text in a textarea.
If there's any email present the form should fail.

I did regex to fail if there is no email present `regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/` and it should be easy to do the negation but I'm not having any success.

Comment: Are you aware there is just a rule |email to check if it's a real e-mail address?
E-mail: The field under validation must be formatted as an e-mail address.

Comment: I know the email rule. But that rule is to check if the input field is a well formed email. What I'm looking for is a validation rule for a textarea that checks that there is no email within that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code into `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method:

```
Validator::extend('not_regex', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    if (!is_string($value) && !is_numeric($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    return !preg_match($parameters[0], $value);
});
```

And then just use your regex like this:

`not_regex:"/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/"`

Comment: That is working ok and it passes if there's any email somewhere in the text. But what I need and not being able to succeed is the oposite: To pass when there's not any email in the text.

Comment: Ah, okay. For some reason there no such validation rule in Laravel, as not_regex, and I think it's only possible with custom validation rule. Do you already try it? I can give you example, if it's needed.

Comment: Great! I was heading that way too since I could not figure out a regex to do the job. But now I'm just stuck in a `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found` Exception. I already tried to put the rules in a array and still not ok. :/

Comment: Yep, don't know why, but Laravel split regex  string on two arguments for validation rule, by comma character at the {2,6}. But you can wrap regex in quotes.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the {2,6}. I don't understand why but the comma gets wrapped  in a `'` character.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is to create your own [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules). This way you can solve this problem using nicely formatted code.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel comes with an "email" validation rule which is very easy to implement. You can read all about it, and other validation methods in [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation).

Comment: I know that rule. Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case, custom validation is your best option!